# Ajax call over https SSL

Tags: c#, ajax, https

I have a jquery Ajax call trying to call a webmethod.  It works for all environment but not once deployed to production.  The only difference is production use HTTPS SSL.

Here is my ajax code

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://www.mywebsite.ca/assure/demandeconfirmee.aspx/EnvoyerAuxAssureurs",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
        },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(thrownError);
        }   
    });
```

and my webmethod

```
[WebMethod]
public static string EnvoyerAuxAssureurs()
{
    return "YanTest";
}
```

Doing ajax over https should be straight forward no?!

on every environment i test it I recieve "yanTest" in response.

However,  under https (production)  I get the following answer (called url is returned in comment..with http instead of https) :

```
 <html><head><title></title><!-- <script language="javascript">window.location.replace("http://www.mywebsite.ca/assure/demandeconfirmee.aspx/EnvoyerAuxAssureurs");</script> --></head><body></body></html>
```

Any input?

**!!!Problem Solved!!!!**
Redirect was caused by my WebPageSecurity.dll module that was causing a redirection,  I've added the following to my web.config and it now works!

```
<secureWebPages mode="On" maintainPath="True" warningBypassMode="AlwaysBypass" bypassQueryParamName="BypassSecurityWarning" ignoreHandlers="WithStandardExtensions">
<files>
    <add path="Assure/DemandeConfirmee.aspx/EnvoyerAuxAssureurs" secure="Ignore" />
</files>
```

Comment: Isn't there any redirect in place? There is no standard problem here. It's something specific of your infraestructure.

Comment: This is what I thought.... however i can't find any redirect in the framework.... why wuould it do this only over https...

Comment: Maybe because you're not logged in?

Comment: I could add a redirect rule only for https. Why don't you check on browser developer tools or Fiddler to see in detail the traffic for that request?

Comment: yess i've checked into "charles proxy" to see the traffic and in chrome developper (XHR request) and I see the request being "200 ok" but the return makes no sens.  I've added a logger inside the webmethod and nothing is loggued.  My WebMethod is never called..... I'll spend some time looking at something that could redirect my request.  The only module that could cause this is "webPageSecurity.dll" which is a library found on internet I have no control over.  Once again,  this problem happen only when behind HTTPS/SSL environment.  Elsewhere,  it works as expected

Comment: Ok that is it,  I've found the solution to my problem, It really was the WebPageSecurity.dll that was causing this redirect,  I've added the following to my web.config and it now works as intended

<secureWebPages mode="On" maintainPath="True" warningBypassMode="AlwaysBypass" bypassQueryParamName="BypassSecurityWarning" ignoreHandlers="WithStandardExtensions">
 <files>
  <add path="Assure/DemandeConfirmee.aspx/EnvoyerAuxAssureurs" secure="Ignore" />
 </files>
</secureWebPages>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

!!!Problem Solved!!!! Redirect was caused by my WebPageSecurity.dll module that was causing a redirection, I've added the following to my web.config and it now works!

```
    <secureWebPages mode="On" maintainPath="True" warningBypassMode="AlwaysBypass" bypassQueryParamName="BypassSecurityWarning" ignoreHandlers="WithStandardExtensions">
<files>
    <add path="Assure/DemandeConfirmee.aspx/EnvoyerAuxAssureurs" secure="Ignore" />
</files>
```